# Why this recursive factorial program only returns the number that I want to calculate?

Tags: recursion, assembly, arm, factorial

I did this simple (non working) program in ARM32:

```
.global main

main:
    mov r0,#5    // 5 is the number that I want to calculate the factorial
    mov r1,r0

factorial:
    cmp r1,#1
    beq end
    sub r1,r1,#1    // n-1
    push {ip,lr}    // save the lr
    bl factorial
    mul r0,r1,r0    // multiply r0 * n-1
    pop {ip,lr}
end:
    bx  lr
```

If I execute it I got 5, instead of 120.

```
$ ./a.out
$ echo $?
5
```

Why?

Comment: By the time you reach `n == 1` and start doing all the multiplications, you have set `r1 = 1`. You should probably save and restore it on the stack.

Comment: Single-step through your code with a debugger to see how register values change.  And think about what exactly the 2 args are that your recursive function accepts, and passes to child calls.  And whether passing 2 args is even valid for a factorial implementation.

Comment: You should have been done with this assignment by now, you are going to struggle with this class.  What happened to the non-recursion version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.global main

main:
    mov r0,#5    // 5 is the number that I want to calculate the factorial
    mov r1,r0

factorial:
    cmp r1,#1
    beq end
    sub r1,r1,#1    // n-1
    push {ip,lr}    // save the lr
    bl factorial
    mul r0,r1,r0    // multiply r0 * n-1
    pop {ip,lr}
end:
    bx  lr
```

walk through your code...

```
mov r0,#5  r0 = 5
mov r1,r0  r1 = 5
cmp r1,#1
beq end 
sub r1,r1,#1  r1 = 4
push
bl factorial
cmp r1,#1
beq end
sub r1,r1,#1 r1 = 3
```

do you see the problem yet? you should already see it by now.

```
and this continues a few more times until
sub r1,r1,#1 r1 = 1
push
bl factorial
cmp r1,#1
beq end
bx lr
mul r0,r1,r0   r0 = 1 * 5 = 5
pop
bx lr
cmp r1,#1
beq end
bx lr
mul r0,r1,r0   r0 = 1 * 5 = 5
...
```

try it without recursion first, and remember for recursion, you will need a local variable that changes for each call in this case and you need to think about where you are placing the comparison if you want to use a single value or if you want to use two,  The ip in the push is just to keep the stack aligned so remember that as you can use that to save one of these registers and restore it on the way out.

Note that from gradeschool

```
4*3*2*1 = 1*2*3*4
```

You need to put some effort in before asking a question at stackoverflow.

Write and debug it in C first (or some language you are stronger in), litter the code with printfs, once you have the algorithm in a language you know then simply re-write it in assembly language or whatever new language you are learning.